# Error installing dependencies with ESLint, the STDIN does not get the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Hello I am configuring with ESLint for do this i do the following steps

- `npm install eslint --save-dev`
- `npx eslint --init`

But when the wizard ask about

> Which style guide do you want to follow?

and select google or airbnb

this ask another question

> Checking peerDependencies of eslint-config-airbnb-base@latest The
>   config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:
>
> eslint-config-airbnb-base@latest eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0
>   eslint-plugin-import@^2.14.0 ? Would you like to install them now with
>   npm? (Y/n)

but the STDIN doesn't work, then I cannot continue with the configuration.

I tried to install the dependencies separately but it did not work

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved installing `npm install inquirer@6.3 --save-dev` first, this is a issue in: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11862